# How do I view my gmail chat/hangout history inside Mutt?

Tags: chat, google-hangouts, mutt

Mutt will not allow me to move to the "Chats" folder, although it is clearly visible when viewed with a web browser. The folder is simply not displayed in Mutt.

I am able to see all my chat history by using the search query "label:chat", so I thought if I create a filter to match these items, and assign them a label - maybe Mutt will see this new label.

Alas, Mutt sees the new label, but displays no items.

How do I view my chat/hangout history inside Mutt?

Answer (score 0):

IMAP is disabled by default for the Chats label in Gmail.

You can enable it in the settings under the labels tab, by selecting "Show in IMAP".

```
Settings (top-right) --> Labels --> Chats --> [X] Show in IMAP
```

Or follow this link: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/labels

Comment: I tried this solution, but it only shows old chats. It seems this does not work for newer history.